# Can't change the icon of a Google Maps marker from a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps API to make a map that retrieves data from the database and shows the corresponding markers on the map. I did this by following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

What I'm now trying to do is create a page (called add_marker.php) that has a draggable marker so that the user can then add the new marker to the database based on the coordinates. I want to be able to see the other markers when I'm on this page. I also include the map code in all the pages so I don't want it to change drastically just for this page, so my approach is the following: Make the draggable marker invisible in all the pages except for the add_marker page by setting the icon setting to an empty string " ". Now the problem is, I can't change the icon's image so I can see it in the particular page I want it visible. I've searched quite a bit here in stackoverflow and found some solution, but none of these worked. 
The error that I get is: add_marker.php:9 Uncaught Reference Error: drag_marker is not defined
(Even though I've made the marker variable global)

The code is the following:

map_code.php (This is the page that I made with the help of the link and is almost identical to that code except for some variable names. It's included in the files that use the map)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
          <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY"
                    type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            var drag_marker;
            function load() {
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.511769, 22.371699),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
              });
              var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

              downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                  var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                  var content = markers[i].getAttribute("content");
                  var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
                      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
                  var content = markers[i].getAttribute("content");
                  var icon = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
                  });


                  bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, content, name);
                }
              });

                *var uluru = {lat: 37.52, lng: 22.37};
                drag_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  icon: " ",
                  draggable: true,
                  position: uluru,
                  map: map
                });*

            }

            function SelectElement(valueToSelect)
            {    

            var element = document.getElementById("markerList");
            element.value = valueToSelect;

            }

            function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name) {
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);

                infoWindow.open(map, marker);

                        infoWindow.setContent("<p>" + name + "<br />" + 
                         html + "<br />");   

                SelectElement(name);

              });
            }

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
              var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                  new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                  new XMLHttpRequest;

              request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                  request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                  callback(request, request.status);
                }
              };

              request.open('GET', url, true);
              request.send(null);
            }

            function doNothing() {}

          </script>

          </head>

          <body onload="load()">
            <div id="map" style="width: 99.5%; height: 40%"></div>
          </body>

        </html>
```

add_marker.php:

```
<html>
 <head>

  <title>My website</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">

        drag_marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png");


        </script>';
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="container">
   <div id="header">
    <h1><a href="Home.php"><img src="logo.png" align="center" alt="logo" style="width:300px;height:60px;"></a><a href="http://gav.uop.gr/"><img src="gavlab.png" align="right" alt="logo" style="width:200px;height:55px;"></a></h1>

   </div>

   <div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
     <h3>Πλοήγηση</h3>
     <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="Home.php">Homepage</a></li>
      <li align="left"><a href="Map.php">Map</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Admin log-in</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.php">info</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.php">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="main">
     <h6 align="center">Map</h6>

     <?php   include("map_code.php");   ?>

<div align="center" id="admin_menu">

 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_WARNING );
//http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/3/F/I/0/A/google-maps-marker-for-residencelamontagne-hi.png
//        icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png",
  SESSION_START();

     if($_SESSION['username'] == "admin"||$_SESSION['username'] == "username"){
        echo '<p align="center" style="color:#8A2908"> Welcome <a href="logout.php"> εδώ.</a></p>';

    $con= mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    mysql_select_db('qr code');
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $con);


    $sql="SELECT * FROM array1";

    $records=mysql_query($sql);

    echo '<form id="main_form" name = "add_new_marker" action="marker_info.php" method="post">';


    '</form>';

    }
        else echo '<p align="center" style="color:#8A2908">Please log in <a href="index.php"> εδώ.</a></p>';     

    ?>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
    Copyright &copy; 2016 Name Here
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is add_map.php ?? it have no any google maps library loaded, or any JS at all, so for sure "drag_marker" is undefined, since it defined in totally another file, more over, drag_marker will be undefined until you set it (after map was loaded)

Comment: You probably mean "add_marker.php" which is the page that lets you add a marker on the map. The file that defines drag_marker is included in the main file (add_map) so I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, add_marker, and missed that include, really confused with that both of them have full document structure (<doctype><head/><body/>) that shouldn't be included in the partials, so ... JS in the <head> of add_mark runs first, so in that moment there is no your variable

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. The drag_marker variable acts like it's a function variable and I can't even run in the same file (only in the load function in which the variable is initialized) even though I've defined it at the start of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use the `drag_marker` variable before it is defined (and probably also before it is initialized, look at the HTML/JavaScript rendered in the browser).

To deal with the timing issue, try:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
 drag_marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png");
}):
```

Comment: I moved that code after the SESSION_START(); part, but now it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setIcon' of undefined. I'm a total newbie in javascript... Where should I move it?

Comment: Sounds like you are now running it after it is defined, but before it is initialized, you need to run that code after the `load` function runs.

Comment: I've tried running it in various points in the code, but I always get the same error. When does the load funtion run? Once I include the file that contains it?

Comment: When the body "onload" event fires.

Comment: It seems that the drag_marker variable behaves like a function local variable. I can only run drag_marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png");  in the load function (right before the end) and I can't even run it in the same local file (map_code.php). Any idea why this is? I've defined the variable in the beginning of the file.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with position in the file, it has to do with sequence (when the code runs)

Comment: I really can't find the error and it is really weird. Do I have to use debugging tools? I've never done this. I'm thinking of copying the code I need into a new file just to move on :P